# Tying a JTree selection to an external collection?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a `JPanel` that acts like a canvas with elements, and the listed elements in a `JTree` next to the panel. Now, I have my element selection on the `JPanel` implemented and it contains elements which implement the `TreeNode` interface, and are essentially the nodes of the tree.

Is it possible to tie the tree selection to that collection directly, so that I can synchronize both selections without writing too much code?

I've looked into the `TreeSelectionModel` interface, but that seems a bit overkill. What I was hoping to get is a built in class that takes a collection in it's constructor or something trivial like that.

I would post a sscce, but my project at this moment is very unclean and there would be a ton of code that's not really relevant.

My `JTree` uses a `DefaultTreeModel` that has my root node (`Workspace`) as the only argument of it's constructor. Now, my `Workspace` has a collection of `TreeNode`s that represent the model of my diagram. However, the diagram itself is a view that forms painters based on the model.

The model of the diagram also has a collection called `SelectedElements` which adds and removes elements based on the selection (done through clicks or lasso).

Comment: `"...TreeSelectionModel interface, but that seems a bit overkill."` -- why do you say this?

Comment: Consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) to better inform us of your problem.

Comment: Well, implementing the interface from scratch requires me to implement a bunch of methods, and if I understood it correctly (though it's quite possible I haven't), the default selection model works with the full paths of the nodes, while I only have the elements (the leafs of the tree) at my disposal.

In the end I'll have to do it like this I think, but I was just wondering if there was an easier way (or if I even understood the scope of the `TreeSelectionModel` intreface.

Comment: There is also of course a default implementation that may be applicable to your problem, although an [sscce](http://sscce.org) would better show us if this were true. I think that while you have only the leaves displayed, you still need to base this display on the full tree. In other words, you should use the JTree's **model** as the basis for your JPanel display. Consider it just another *view* of the same *model*. Then you could share selection listeners as well and with ease.

Answer (score 1):

I think that while you have only the leaves displayed in your JPanel, you still need to base this display on the full tree. In other words, you should use the JTree's **model** as the basis for your JPanel display. Consider it just another *view* of the same *model*. Then you could share selection listeners as well and with ease, and wouldn't  even need to create any new TreeSelectionListener but rather simply use the same one that the JTree has.

Comment: I would post a sscce, but my project at this moment is very unclean and there would be a ton of code that's not really relevant.

My `JTree` uses a `DefaultTreeModel` that has my root node (`Workspace`) as the only argument of it's constructor. Now, my `Workspace` has a collection of `TreeNode`s that represent the model of my diagram. However, the diagram itself is a view that forms painters based on the model.

The model of the diagram also has a collection called `SelectedElements` which adds and removes elements based on the selection (done through clicks or lasso).

Comment: @user2352164: the only way for me to test my idea is for me to create an sscce and test it, but I don't have the time. If you need further help from me, your SSCCE would be much appreciated.